# Optimize sum of neighbor points 3D

Tags: matlab

I have a materials matrix where the values indicate the type of material (value between 1 and 8). Each value below 5 indicates an "interesting" material. Now at a certain point, i want to sum up the amount of non-interesting neighbor materials. So in a 3D-matrix the result at one point can be value between 0 and 6. One of the problems is that the "current" point is at the edge of the 3D matrix. I can solve this using 3 very expensive for-loops:

```
materials; % given 3D matrix i.e. 97*87*100
matrixSize = size(materials);
n = matrixSize(1)*matrixSize(2)*matrixSize(3); * total number of points
materialsFlattened = reshape(materials, [n 1]); % flattened materials matrix from a 3D matrix to a 1D matrix
pageSize = matrixSize(1)*matrixSize(2); % size of a page in z-direction

interestingMaterials = materialsFlattened(:) < 5; % logical vector indicating if the materials are interesting

n_bc = zeros(obj.n, 1); % amount of neighbour non-interesting materials
for l = 1:matrixSize(3) % loop over all z
    for k = 1:matrixSize(2) % loop over all y
                for j = 1:matrixSize(1) % loop over all x
                    n_bc(sub2ind(matrixSize,j,k,l)) = ...
                        ~interestingMaterials(sub2ind(matrixSize,j,k,max(1, l-1)))...
                      + ~interestingMaterials(sub2ind(matrixSize,j,max(1,k-1),l))...
                      + ~interestingMaterials(sub2ind(matrixSize,max(1, j-1),k,l))...
                      + ~interestingMaterials(sub2ind(matrixSize,min(matrixSize(1),j+1),k,l))...
                      + ~interestingMaterials(sub2ind(matrixSize,j,min(matrixSize(2),k+1),l))...
                      + ~interestingMaterials(sub2ind(matrixSize,j,k,min(matrixSize(3),l+1)));
                end
            end
        end
```

So note that i first flatten the matrix to a 1D matrix using reshape. The `min` and `max` operators ensure that i do not go out of the bounds of the matrix; instead i take the value of the material where i currently am. For my application, speed is of the essence and i was hoping i can get rid of this ugly loop in loop structure. Often times that is possible in MATLAB, as the element-wise indexing is amazing and sometimes kinda magic.

Comment: Please post a small example with input and desired output. Your code cannot be run as is

Comment: You want to do convolutions for this. A summing convolution would do. This is literally the example is given to students to why convolutions are fast! It would be easy for you to find some material on it :D

Comment: @Ander The OP seems to already have a lot of _materials_ :-D

Comment: @AnderBiguri i do not get it to work. I have tried creating an "unflattened" matrix with only 0 and 1's (so a 3D matrix indicating if the point is interesting or not) and then use convolution: ```convn(~interestingMaterials3D, 1, 'same')```. But the result differs from using the 3 nested for-loops.

Comment: My previous comment was a bit premature, i have done some more research and i think it almost does what i want now. I first create a kernel: ```kernel(:,:,1)=[0 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 0]; kernel(:,:,2) = [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]; kernel(:,:,3) = [0 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 0];``` and then i do a convolution on the unflattened matrix: ```convn(~interestingMaterials3D, kernel, 'same');``` The result is not identical to that with the nested for-loops. But i think that is due to what happens at the edges of the 3D matrix. I want to use the "last" material from the 3D matrix.

Comment: If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use `imfilter` instead, which has options for  boundary conditions. You can also just pad your matrix with a row (plane) in each boundary, with whichever values you want there.

Comment: You are awesome thanks. With ```imfilter``` i can 100% replicate my question. For now i will just keep using ```convn```, because the boundaries do not matter too much.